# wrong animation when sliding using intro slider

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, animation, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager looks like intro slider and i want to start uptodown and downtoup animation alternatively when sliding through sliders:

my pager adapter code is:

```
public class mpageradapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final int[] Layouts;
public mpageradapter(FragmentManager fm, int [] Layouts) {
    super(fm);
    this.Layouts=Layouts;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:return new first_slide();
        case 1:return new second_slide();
        case 2:return new third_slide();
        case 3:return new final_slide();
        default:return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Layouts.length;
}
```

}

and my fragment sliders code is:

```
public class first_slide extends Fragment {
RelativeLayout t1,t2;
Animation uptodown,downtoup;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    uptodown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.uptodown);
    downtoup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.downtoup);
    t1.startAnimation(uptodown);
    t2.startAnimation(downtoup);
    Log.i("first", "onStart: first");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_slide,container,false);
    t1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t2 = (RelativeLayout)view. findViewById(R.id.t2);
  return view;
}
```

}

the wrong is when sliding the first and third is animating and the second and third is not.
I think it because that the viewpager is creating the first two at first and after sliding from th second to the third the viewpager create the third and fourth
how can I animate every fragment uptodown and downtoup alternativly when i navigate through the intro slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the animation issue in intro screen in viewpager.
If I have understand your question correctly might my answer help you or give hint..
I have used setUserVisibleHint() to check if fragment is visible to user or not isLoaded boolean flag to check if the fragment is loaded or not.

```
private boolean isVisibleToUser = false;
private boolean isLoaded = false;
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    Log.e("isVisibleToUser  " + isVisibleToUser + " isLoaded : " + isLoaded);

    this.isVisibleToUser = isVisibleToUser;

    if (isVisibleToUser && isLoaded) {
        playAnimation();
    }
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onboarding_screen1, container, false);
    handler = new Handler();

    if (isVisibleToUser && (!isLoaded)) {
                init();
                playAnimation();
                isLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```